# Coin Change analysis

Tags: algorithm

{1,3,5} denomination coins; Sum = 11.
find minimum number of coins which can be used to make the sum
(We can use any number of coins of each denomination)

I searched for Run Time complexity of this Coin change problem particularly using dynamic programming method. But was not able to find explanation anywhere.

How to calculate the complexity of non dynamic solution and then change it for the dynamic one? (not the greedy one)

**Edit:**

Here is an implementation for which analysis was asked.

```
public int findCoinChange(int[] coins, int sum,int count) {

    int ret = 0, maxRet = -1;
    if(sum ==0)maxRet = count;
    else if(sum < 0)maxRet = -1;
    else{
        for(int i:coins){
            ret = findCoinChange(coins, sum - i,count+1);
            if(maxRet< 0)maxRet = ret;
            else if(ret >=0 && ret < maxRet){
                    maxRet = ret;
                }
            }
    }
    if(maxRet < 0)return -1;
    else return maxRet;
}
```

Looks like Combinatorial explosion to me. However I am not sure how to deduce a run time complexity for this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986828/coin-changing-algorithm

Comment: I think greedy will not work for this problem.

Comment: thefourtheye - Greedy will not always give best solution e.g. Sum=9;{1,4,5} Greedy will give - {5,1,1,1,1} optimal is {4,4}

Comment: @arpitgautam Correct. Thats what I meant. If a program works for certain inputs and fails for others, it wont be considered as a correct program. So greedy will not work. And your example in the comment should read {4, 5}

Comment: Right, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The [dynamic programming solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986865/45914) to this problem is *clearly* `O(k * n)` (nested loops, blah blah blah) where `k` is the number of coins and `n` is the amount of money that change is being made for.

I don't know what you mean by non-dynamic programming solution. Sorry, you're going to have specify what algorithm you mean. The [greedy algorithm fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986865/45914) in some cases, so you *shouldn't* be referring to that. Do you mean the linear programming solution? That's a terrible approach to this problem because we don't know what the complexity is, and it's possible to make it run arbitrarily slowly.

I also don't know what you mean by "change it for the dynamic one."

Comment: You are correct, greedy and linear are not the way to go. I am referring to using recursion. We try to reduce the problem to a sub problem by subtracting a denomination from sum and then solving the sub problem. If we got a zero at the end, we have a traceable path and after all solutions, we do look for smallest one.

Comment: The question was about analyzing complexity of recursive solution to coin change problem. It was not about greedy/dp solutions.
I gave it a shot - The recursive tree is `n * k` deep at most. But it has lots of branches with duplicates. I dont know how to proceed from there.

Comment: @Raghu: From the question: "*I searched for Run Time complexity of this Coin change problem particularly using dynamic programming method. But was not able to find explanation anywhere.*"

Comment: The complexity of the recursive solution will follow much like a recursive solution for calculating the Fibonacci sequence.  However, Fib builds a binary tree and the complexity is easily seen to be O(2^n) the change making is going to be dependent on the number and size of the coins in your denomination E.G. set D={1, 5, 12, 25} as N gets larger, more of the denomination set will come into play causing a higher number of children toward the root of the tree.  I think, in general you could safely say O(k^n).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem for the complexity analysis, this problem is a special case of the integer knapsack problem, it is weakly np hard and can be solve in pseudo-polynomial time.