# Coin exchange method with value of power of 2 PYTHON

Tags: python, coin-change

Once the machines take over, the denomination of every coin will be a power of two: 1-cent, 2-cent, 4-cent, 8-cent, 16-cent, etc. There will be no limit to how much a coin can be worth.

A set of coins makes change for n if the sum of the values of the coins is n. For example, the following sets make change for 7:

7 1-cent coins
5 1-cent, 1 2-cent coins
3 1-cent, 2 2-cent coins
3 1-cent, 1 4-cent coins
1 1-cent, 3 2-cent coins
1 1-cent, 1 2-cent, 1 4-cent coins
Thus, there are 6 ways to make change for 7.

**Write a function count_change that takes a positive integer n and returns the number of ways to make change for n using these coins of the future.**

I have been working on this question for an hour trying to use tree recursion but it doesn't work.
I was thinking about to use 2 branches of the current amount - 1 and the current amount - largest coin value possible but the outcomes are never satisfiable.

Please give me a suggestion of how to approach it...thx!

Comment: Where is your current code? What do you mean "doesn't work": errors (provide full traceback), unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: is this a homework question? If so, please show your efforts so far.

Comment: I'm a bit deceived... I opened the question expecting to see what is "the power of 2 python".

Comment: at least, check for existing answers... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518330/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986828/ and quite a few more...

Comment: @isedev actually the dynamic programming solution probably solves this fine ... im way too tired or something

Comment: there I gave you a pretty good place to start using dynamic programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example of dynamic programming

you can implement it with the standard formula for dynamic programming (see [Coin Change Problem](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change))

let `s = {1,5,10,25}` our coinset for now be standard coin denominations

let `f(x,y) = number_of_ways_to_make_change` let `x=change_due;y=allowed_coinset_index`

- **notes**: if y == 0 our allowed coinset is {1}, if y == 1 our allowed coinset is {1,5} ...
- any change_due has a trivial solution of 1 when our coinset consists only of {1} that is to say if you only have pennies there exists only one way to make change (all pennies)
- ergo `f(anything,0) == 1  && f(0,anything) == 1  && f(anything,anthing < 0) == 0`

let us solve for a few change_due values

```
change_due   function_call    
1             f(1,0) = 1
...
4             f(4,0) = 1
5             f(5,1) = f((5-5),1) + f(5,0) = 1 + 1 = 2
...
9             f(9,1) = f(9-5,1)+f(9,0) = f(4,1) + 1 = f(4,0*) + 1 = 1+1 = 2
10            f(10,2) = f(10-10,2) + f(10,1) = f(0,2) + (f(5,1)+f(10,0))= 1+(2+1) = 4
```

so we can see our base cases of

```
f(x,0) = f(0,y) = 1
f(x is less than zero,y) = f(x,y is less than zero) = 0
```

note that this applies for any set of coins

V **this is the important part** V

```
#if x,y are not in above conditions we want to recursively call ourselves allowing us to build up to a complex solution from several simpler solutions
f(x,y) = f(x-CHANGE_DENOM,y) + f(x,y-1)
```

lets keep playing with that table from above and see how many ways we can make 16 cents

```
S = [1,5,10,25] 
# our y is 2 (since S[2] = 10 which is the largest denomination < our change_due(16))
f(16,2) = f(16-S[2],2) + f(16,1) 
        = f(16-10,2) + f(16,1) = f(6,2) + f(16,1)
   f(6,2) = f(6-S[2]) + f(6,1) = 0 + f( 6,1) = 0+2#(see below) =
   f(16,1) = f(16-S[1],1) + f(16,0) = f(11,1) + 1
       f(11,1) = f(11-S[1],1) + f(11,0) = f(6,1) + 1
          f(6,1) = f(6-S[1],1) + f(6,0) = f(1,1) + 1
             f(1,1) = f(1-S[1],1) + f(1,0) = 0 + 1 = 1
          f(6,1) = f(1,1) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
       f(11,1) = f(6,1) + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3
   f(16,1) = f(11,1) + 1 = 3+1 = 4
f(16,2) = f(6,2) + f(16,1) = 2 + 4  = 6 ways to make change for 16 cents
```

now you just need to make it work for your bigger coinset

Comment: 6 is not a power of two - for due = 6...