# Dynamic programming: which recurrence relation do we use?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence, coin-change

At the cash register of a store we want to give change of worth V cents of euro. Create and analyze a greedy algorithm that gives the change using the minimum number of coins.

Assume that the available coins are the euro subdivisions, i.e. {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50} and that we have an unlimited number of coins for each subdivision.

For this question I have done the following pseudocode:

```
Algorithm min_number_coins (C, V)

Input: array C={1,2,5,10,20,50} in ascending order and given value V

Output: array A with minum number of coins

A <- ∅

for i <- 5 downto 0 do

    while V >= C[i] do

        A <- A U C[i]

        V <- V - C[i]

    if V = 0 then

        return A
```

Is that correct? At the for loop is it correct to take i from 5 or do I have to set a new variable n = length(C) ?

For the complexity: In the worst case we need V coins for the change, if we have only the subdivision 1. So the complexity of the for-loop and so also of the algorithm is O(V), right?

Now I am asked the following:

Generalizing the above problem, we have the set of different coins {c_0, c_1, ... , c_n} with c_0 <c_1 < ...  <c_n from which we want to give the change of value V using the minimum number of coins. We consider that c_0 = 1.

Create and analyze a dynamic programming algorithm that finds an optimal solution to the problem, commenting on both time and space complexity of the algorithm.

Could you explain to me the idea how we use the dynamic programming here? I mean the recurrence relation  that we have to use. I haven't really undersood that.

Comment: "Dynamic programming" as used on so-called competition sites, is basically only a fancy term for caching. When calculating results, store it so it doesn't have to be calculated again.

Comment: Yes! But how is this idea related to the coin problem? Which subproblems do we get? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Basically, anything you need to calculate more than once is such a "sub-problem", and if your abstract algorithm doesn't do that then "dynamic programming" doesn't make sense. IMO it's often more used as an implentation detail.

Comment: So is this case the subproblems are the minimum combination of coins to get the value i, for each i from 0 to V ? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @MaryStar yes. You can identify the subproblems using the recurrence relation as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coin changing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986828/coin-changing-algorithm)

Comment: I read the answer of that link but I am a little confused. What I have understood is the following: We have the coins 1 = c0 < c1 < ... < cn. 

C(i , j) is the problem to give change of worth j with the coins c0, c1, ..., ci. 

Our goal is to to solve C(n , V). 

Considering the problem C(i, j), there are two cases. 
 - Case 1: If we don't use the coin ci then we consider also the next coin. So our new problem is C(i-1 , j). 
 - Case 2: If we use the coin ci then the remaining value is j - ci. So our new problem C(i, j - ci). Are these two cases correct? @AbhinavMathur

Comment: @MaryStar yes, that partially makes up the recurrence relation as well

Comment: What is missing so that it becomes complete? @AbhinavMathur